# Sintaxe ElapsedEventHandler no System.Timers.Timer

Tags: c#

Há diferença entre iniciar um `Timer` assim:

```
_timerExam = new Timer();
_timerExam.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
_timerExam.Interval = 1000;
_timerExam.Start();
```

E assim?

```
_timerExam = new Timer();
_timerExam.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
_timerExam.Interval = 1000;
_timerExam.Start();
```

Para o que serve o `ElapsedEventHandler`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso se chama `Method Group Conversion`, uma funcionalidade incluída com o C# 2.

No C# 1, você obrigatoriamente tinha que escrever o construtor do `delegate` passando como parâmetro a ação (`action`) daquele delegate.

```
_timerExam.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
```

No C# 2 as coisas mudaram, agora você pode deixar o compilador decidir o tipo `delegate` compatível com a assinatura do seu método (`OnTimedEvent`) e assinatura do evento alvo (`Elapsed`). A partir daí o compilador gera o `delegate` apropriado.

```
_timerExam.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
```

Isso é um "truque" ou açúcar sintático do compilador para diminuir a quantidade de código escrito pelo programador. No código compilado o operador `new` é usado como se você tivesse escrito ele.